# proof check, ($ E(X^p)=\int_0^\infty px^{p-1}\mathbb{P}\{ X>x \}dx $)

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, expectation

> **Problem:** 
>   If $X ≥ 0,$ then for every $p \in R_+,$
>   $$ E(X^p)=\int_0^\infty px^{p-1}\mathbb{P}\{ X>x \}dx  $$
>   Show this, using Fubini's theorem with the product measure 
>   $ \mathbb{P}\times Leb, $
>   after noting that 
>   $ X^{p}(\omega)=\int_0^\infty px^{p-1}dx=\int_0^\infty px^{p-1} \chi_{\{ X>x \}}(\omega) dx. $

Actually, I have problems with the notations. I have passed measure theory but I have problems with this probability theory. This a problem from Erhan Çinar's book.

**Here is what I have done**

> Let
>   $ \mu [-\infty , x]= P(X\leq x) $
>   so
>   $ \mu [x , +\infty]= P(X\geq x) $
>   then
>   $$ \int_0^\infty  d\mu(y)=\int_x^\infty \mathbb{P}\{ X>y \}dy, $$
>   Now I want to write 
>   $$\int_0^\infty px^{p-1}\mathbb{P}\{ X>x \}dx=\int_0^\infty px^{p-1}(\int_x^\infty  d\mu(y))dx=\int_0^\infty\int_0^y px^{p-1}\mathbb{P}\{ X>y \}dxd\mu(y)= \int_0^\infty y^{p}\mathbb{P}\{ X>y \}d\mu(y)=E(X^p)$$

**Please let me know where my problem is?**

Comment: This doesn't look right: $$ \int_0^\infty  d\mu(y)=\int_x^\infty \mathbb{P}\{ X>y \}dy$$ The RHS is a function of $x$, but the LHS Is not.

Comment: Rewrite $$   E(X^{p}) = E (   \int _{0}^\infty 1_{X>x}  px^{p-1} \text{d} x )=    \int _{0}^\infty E(1_{X>x}  px^{p-1} )\text{d} x =\int _{0}^\infty px^{p-1}  E(1_{X>x}  )\text{d} x $$

Comment: Relevant https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/985099/why-is-the-expected-value-of-xp-equal-to-p-int-0-inftyyp-1-mathbb?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint 
$$|X(w)|^p =\int_{0}^{|X(w)|} pt^{p-1} dt= \int_{0}^{\infty} pt^{p-1} \mathbf{1}_{\{|X|>t\}}(w)dt
 $$

AND

$$E(X^p)=\int_\Omega |X(w)|^p dw   =\int_\Omega\int_{0}^{\infty} pt^{p-1} \mathbf{1}_{\{|X|>t\}}(w)dt~dw.=\int_{0}^{\infty} pt^{p-1} 
 \int_\Omega\mathbf{1}_{\{|X|>t\}}(w)dw ~dt
$$
and $$ 
\mathbb{P}\{ X>t \}= \int_\Omega \mathbf{1}_{\{|X|>t\}}(w) dw.$$ 
which gives the result.

Comment: after first $dt$ we have equality?

Comment: I have edited reload your page

Comment: but according to the problem we have
$ E(X^p)=\int_0^\infty px^{p-1}\mathbb{P}\{ X>x \}dx  $

we have this $\mathbb{P}\{ X>x \}$ which I don't know what it means

Comment: yes use Fubini from the last line . to get that answer

Comment: see the edit aigain.