# Fubini's theorem and reparameterisation

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Consider the accepted answer to [the following question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/985099/explain-why-exp-p-int-0-inftyyp-1pxy-dy) which says

> It's Fubini's theorem .  The domain of the double integral is:
> $(\omega,y)\in\Omega\times [0, |X(\omega)|]$, however the outer
> integral is with respect to the measure of the outcomes. $\mathrm
>  d\mathbb P\equiv \mathbb P(\mathrm d \omega)$.  So when we apply
> Fubini's theorem the new inner integral is simply the cumulative
> measure.
>
> Via:
>
> $$\begin{align}\mathbb{E}|X|^p &
> =\int_{\Omega}p\left(\int_0^{|X(\omega)|}y^{p-1}\,\mathrm d y \right)\,\mathbb{P}(\mathrm d\omega) \\ & = p\int_0^\infty
>  y^{p-1}\left(\int_{\Omega:y<|X(\omega)|} \mathbb{P}(\mathrm
>  d\omega)\right)\,\mathrm d y \\ & = p\int_0^\infty y^{p-1}\mathbb
>  P(y<|X|)\,\mathrm d y \end{align}$$

I understand the first equality, this is just rewriting $|X|$. However, I do not understand how one goes from the first to the second line. The author suggests that this is due to Fubini. But this is not immediate according to the version I have:

> Theorem 4.22 (Fubini's theorem) (i) If $f$ is non-negative measurable,
> then $$ \int_E f \mathrm{~d} \mu=\int_{E_1}\left(\int_{E_2}
>  f\left(x_1, x_2\right) \mu_2\left(\mathrm{~d} x_2\right)\right)
>  \mu_1\left(\mathrm{~d} x_1\right) . $$ In particular, we have $$
>  \int_{E_1}\left(\int_{E_2} f\left(x_1, x_2\right)
>  \mu_2\left(\mathrm{~d} x_2\right)\right) \mu_1\left(\mathrm{~d}
>  x_1\right)=\int_{E_2}\left(\int_{E_1} f\left(x_1, x_2\right)
>  \mu_1\left(\mathrm{~d} x_1\right)\right) \mu_2\left(\mathrm{~d}
>  x_2\right) . $$ This is sometimes known as Tonelli's theorem. (ii) If
> $f$ is integrable, and $$ A=\left\{x_1 \in E:
>  \int_{E_2}\left|f\left(x_1, x_2\right)\right| \mu_2\left(\mathrm{~d}
>  x_2\right)<\infty\right\} . $$ then $$ \mu_1\left(E_1 \backslash
>  A\right)=0 . $$ If we set $$
> f_1\left(x_1\right)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} \int_{E_2} f\left(x_1,
>  x_2\right) \mu_2\left(\mathrm{~d} x_2\right) & x_1 \in A \\ 0 & x_1
>  \notin A \end{array},\right. $$ then $f_1$ is a $\mu_1$ integrable
> function and $$ \mu_1\left(f_1\right)=\int_E f \mathrm{~d} \mu $$

My issue is that $E_2$ should not depend on $E_1$ as in the theorem. But in the given application the author seems to do the following

1. Take their union (in 2-D)
2. Reparameterise it in the form of the second line
3. Claim that this is due to Fubini.

I am struggling to see how this makes sense.

**Question:** Could someone help me understand why
$$\begin{align}\int_{\Omega}p\left(\int_0^{|X(\omega)|}y^{p-1}\,\mathrm d y \right)\,\mathbb{P}(\mathrm d\omega) & = p\int_0^\infty
 y^{p-1}\left(\int_{\Omega:y<|X(\omega)|} \mathbb{P}(\mathrm
 d\omega)\right)\,\mathrm d y  \end{align}$$
In particular, how does this follow from Fubini's Theorem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}$Well, "really" we integrate: $$\int_\Omega\int_0^\infty f\cdot\chi_{\{(\omega,y):y<|X(\omega)|\}}\d y\d\omega$$Where $f$ is $(\omega,y)\mapsto py^{p-1}$. Assuming you're satisfied that Fubini allows us to exchange the order we get this equal to: $$\int_0^\infty\int_\Omega f\cdot\chi_{\{(\omega,y):y<|X(\omega)|\}}\d\omega\d y$$So far, not mysterious - I hope. Our domains of integration are constant, there is no reparametrising. Now let's get rid of the indicator function: $$\int_0^\infty\int_{\{\Omega:y<|X(\omega)\}}f\d\omega\d y$$

Happy? This trick is common. Indicator functions are theoretically useful :)

Answer (score 9):

The crux is given in [the other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/986618/592552) to the question you quoted:

\begin{align*}
&\int_{\Omega}p\left(\int_0^{|X(\omega)|}y^{p-1}\,\mathrm d y \right)\,\mathbb{P}(\mathrm d\omega)\\
&= \int_{\Omega}p\left(\int_0^\infty y^{p-1} \mathbf{1}_{[0,|X|(\omega))}(y)\,\mathrm d y \right)\,\mathbb{P}(\mathrm d\omega)\\
&= \int_0^\infty p\left(\int_{\Omega} y^{p-1} \mathbf{1}_{[0,|X|(\omega))}(y)\,\mathbb{P}(\mathrm d\omega) \right)\,\mathrm d y\\
& = p\int_0^\infty
 y^{p-1}\left(\int_{\{\omega\in\Omega:y<|X(\omega)|\}} \mathbb{P}(\mathrm
 d\omega)\right)\,\mathrm d y
\end{align*}

Comment: Excellent answer. The only reason I didn't put it as accepted is that the other was of similar content but posted a second earlier. Still, thank you for your contribution.

Comment: @MathsWizzard A bit unfortunate - we posted our answers within $26$ seconds of each other (exactly) - and the answers are more or less the same